# Is there a generic representation for non-quasi split $p$-adic group?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms

It seems that generic representation only occurs for quasi-split groups.

For non-quasi split groups, is it expected that generic representation doesn’t exist?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think of genericity as having a Whittaker model, and of the Whittaker model as defined by induction from the unipotent radical of a Borel subgroup.  Without a Borel, what is the definition of genericity?

Comment: @LSpice, oh, I got to know what I am missing! Thank you very much!

Comment: You can have generic parameters though, and some partial analogues, like kirillov models for GL(2,D)

Comment: @Kimball, thank you very much for illumination.